# Generate data after selection list choice

Tags: php, sql, selection, populate

Say i have a form with a postcode field (`text`) and a school field (`selection`), currently i am able to populate the selection list with names of the schools from the database but i want the postcode that is linked with the chosen school to automatically populate :

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "twa312", "dam6av9a");
mysqli_select_db(twa312, $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysqli_error() );

$options = '<option value="0"></option>';

$sql = "SELECT school_info.name AS name, local_schools.postcodeID AS postcode FROM school_info INNER JOIN local_schools ON local_schools.schoolID = school_info.schoolID";
$rs = mysqli_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error());
```

Comment: There are two ways, one using ajax, 2nd way to populate array in js and onchange get value from js array and populate value.

Comment: what would be the JS method?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible solutions for this. Generating javascript array with school id as key and postcode as value. And on option change set post field value accordingly. Or using ajax to load it from database.

For example you can generate something like this:

```
<script> 
    var postcode_list = JSON.decode('<?php echo json_encode($postcode_array);?>');
    // put this function inside select on change method
    // also if you load default value you can add to onload method
    function update_postcode(){
        var select_val = jQuery("#primary").val();

        var postcode = postcode_list['+ select_val +'];

        //checking if we have such value
        if(typeof postcode != 'undefined'){
            jQuery("#post").val(); 
        }
</script>
```

Code might not work, not tested.

Comment: would this be the ajax method? if so what would be the method that uses a javascript array?

Comment: this is array method, ajax probably would use jQuery.ajax('url to call').done(function(response){// check if succeeded, load values});